# Show that $\varphi: (\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}))' \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^\infty$ defined by $ f \mapsto (f(1), f(x), f(x^2), \dots)$ is surjective

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove that the dual of the vector space of polynomials $(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}))'$ and $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ are isomorphic.

So I need to show that $\varphi: (\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}))' \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^\infty$ defined by $ f \mapsto (f(1), f(x), f(x^2), \dots)$ is an invertible linear map.

I'm a little stuck on the surjective condition. Here is what I'm trying to do:

We want to show that $\forall (u_1, u_2, \dots) \in \mathbb{R}^\infty, \exists f:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$, such that $\varphi(f)= (u_1, u_2, \dots)$.

This would imply that we need to find an $f$ such that $u_1=f(1)$, $u_2=f(x)$, $u_3=f(x^2) \dots$

**Question 1:**
I'm interpreting $f$ as the the functional that takes a polynomial and evaluates it at some fixed number. (e.g. $f$ is the functional that evaluates a polynomial at 3). Is this correct?

**Question 2:** If I'm right in Question 1, how is it possible that for arbitrary $u_2$ and $u_3$ such that $u_3 \neq u_2^2$, we can have $x$ and $x^2$ evaluated at the same number, satisfy both $u_2=f(x)$ and $u_3=f(x^2)$?

Any tips as to how to proceed would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ is $\Bbb R$-isomorphic to the $\Bbb R$-vector space $$\mathcal V:=\big\{\{a_n\}:a_n=0\text{ for all but finitely many }n\big\}.$$ So that, $\big(\mathcal P(\Bbb R)\big)'$ is $\Bbb R$-isomorphic to $\mathcal V'$. Now to show, $\mathcal V'$ is $\Bbb R$-isomorphic to $\Bbb R^{\infty}$ consider the map, $\Phi:\mathcal V'\to \Bbb R^{\infty}$ defined by $$\Phi(f)=\big(f(e_1),f(e_1+e_2),f(e_1+e_2+e_3),...\big),\forall f\in \mathcal V',$$ where $e_k\in \mathcal V$ is the sequence whose $k$-th term is $1$ and all other terms of $e_k$ are $0$ for each $k\in \Bbb N$.

Note that, $\{e_k:k\in \Bbb N\}$ forms a basis of $\mathcal V$, so that, the linear map $\Phi$ is injective. To prove surjectivity of $\Phi$, consider $(u_1,u_2,...)\in \Bbb R^{\infty}$ and define a $f\in \mathcal V'$ on the above basis as follows: $$f(e_1)=u_1,$$ $$f(e_2)=u_2-u_1,$$$$f(e_3)=u_3-u_2-u_1,$$$$....$$

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Could you clarify what you mean here? $\mathcal V:=\big\{\{a_n\}:a_n=0\text{ for all but finitely many }n\big\}$?

Comment: Are you just putting the coefficients of each polynomial into a set, and adding zeros thereafter? i.e. $x^2 + 2x + 4 $ is $\{1,2,4,0,0,0,0 \dots\}$?

Comment: Exactly, you are in right.